# Dispose session objects

Tags: session, struts2, server-side, dispose

Is it possible to dispose of objects that are stored in the session in struts2?

Some of the objects I would like to store in the session have resources that need to be released, but I can't find a way to dispose of them cleanly when the session times out or is closed.

I realize that client-based solutions require a javascript timer, but I'm not worried about the client side right now. I just want to be able to clean the resources up on the server-side when the session times out.

I thought about checking the sessions (plural because there can be many concurrent sessions with different clients) on each request and performing late cleanup, but at that point the session map is already gone.

Comment: Session is a concern of the application server, so no there is no practical way to dispose of the session and I would never advise trying to do so. I'm of the mind that little should be stored in the session, enough to look up what is needed from other sources when needed. Say there is a user object set in the session, simply remove that object from the session map and GC will dispose of it.

Comment: I missed the clean up aspect. If the allocation requires special clean up most certainly the session is the wrong place. You service layer is the correct place, and I think you would need to implement another timing system, a lot of good things are said of quartz. You would create an interceptor which resets the timer for that user, when the timer expires you can now properly do clean up.

Comment: Um... if the session times out, the session is gone. If that session had objects in it, and nothing else holds a reference to that object, then the objects are *already* eligible for GC with no intervention required. There's also session listeners. I don't understand what you need to accomplish.

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest removing objects from the session that require special clean-up that cannot be handled by the auto-GC on session timeout. Instead, store an identifier to that object (no strings attached that can be removed w/o any side effects)

Comment: @Jensen Ching: I think you are on the right track. I'll store the state / resource dependent objects elsewhere and just put identifiers in the session. I discovered that HttpSessionListener should be the hook that I need to know when the session is destroyed. Between the two, I should be able to clean up the resources when the session goes away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from a coworker. Thanks for the suggestions.

It appears the solution is to create a class that implements HttpSessionListener. This interface contains functions that are called when the session is created and destroyed. Then add:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.package.listeners.TestSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

To web.xml or your servlet configuration file.